# how to store image and its path in sql server 2005 using vb2010?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

we are doing a mini project on creating a photo viewer.we are using vb2010  as front end and microsoft sql server 2005 as backend;we were stuck up with reading and storing the picture and its path into the database!

Answer (score 0):

[Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/)